# When I input 1900 for the year and 2 for the month I get 29 when it should be 28

Tags: c++, loops, if-statement, leap-year

> Write a program month.cpp that asks the user to input the year and the month (1-12) and prints the number of days in that month (taking into account leap years). You may not use switch case or arrays even if you know these language constructs.

I understand `using namespace std` is a bad practice. However, my professor wants us to learn like this as of now.

I think I am making a mistake with my loop for February, but I don't know what it might be.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int year = 0;
    int month = 0;
    cout << "Enter year: ";
    cin >> year;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter Month: ";
    cin >> month;
    cout << endl;


    if (month == 1){
        cout << "31 days" << endl;
    }
    if (month == 2){
        if (year % 4){
            cout << "29 days" << endl;
        }
        else{
            cout << "28 days" << endl;

        }
    }    

    if (month == 3){
        cout << "31 days" << endl;
        }
    if (month == 4){
        cout << "30 days" << endl;

    }
    if (month == 5){
        cout << "31 days" << endl;
    }
    if (month == 6) {
        cout << "30 days" << endl;
    }
    if (month == 7){
        cout << "31 days" << endl;
        }
    if (month == 8){
        cout << "31 days" << endl;

    }
    if (month == 9){
        cout << "30 days" << endl;
    }
    if (month == 10) {
        cout << "31 days" << endl;
    }
    if (month == 11){
        cout << "30 days" << endl;
    }
    if (month == 12) {
        cout << "31 days" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: [Leap year](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_year) is more complicated than `year%4 == 0`, there are exception for `%100==0` which has also exception for `%400==0`...

Comment: `if (year % 4)` should be `if (year % 4 == 0)`.  More or less.

Comment: isn't 1900 a leap year? which means 29 is correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem occurs in the `if(year%4)` statement. I'm guessing that you're meaning to say "when the year is divisible by 4, output 29 days".

However, your if-statement does not actually do this.

This if-statement first evaluates `(year%4)` then outputs 29 days if it ends up being true. In C++, an expression is true when it is not equal to 0.

Thus, `year%4` evaluates to true when `year%4` *isn't* equal to zero; it is the exact opposite of what you actually meant to do.

To fix this, simply replace your if-statement with `if(year%4 == 0)`.

EDIT: The leap-year criterion is actually quite a bit more complicated; for a year to be a leap year, it must either be divisible by 400 *or* divisible by 4 and *not* 100.

In the end, the if-statement should look like this:

```
if(month == 2){
    if((year % 400 == 0) || (year%4 == 0 && year%100 != 0)){
        cout << "29 days" << endl;
    }
    else{
        cout << "28 days" << endl;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could find in the internet how the leap year is calculated.

If I am not mistaken then it is calculated the following way

```
( year % 400 == 0 ) || ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 )
```

So `1900` is not a leap year because it is divisible by `100` but not divisible by `400`.

For example the if statement for the February could look like

```
if (month == 2){

    cout << 28 + ( ( year % 400 == 0 ) || ( year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0 ) )
         << " days" << endl;
}
```

Comment: OH I see my mistake now. I should have searched up how it is calculated, terrible mistake. Thank you for your help!